# Expand list of {{t1,x1},...} with new set of t's

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of the form `data={{t1,x1}, {t2,x2},...}` and a list `newt = {nt1,nt2,...}` and I want to expand `data` to these new times to become `{{nt1,x(1)},{nt2,x(2)},{nt3,x(3)},...}` where `x(i)` is equal to the `xi` of whichever data point is preceding `nti`.

I assume that `t1<=t2<=t3<=..`, `nt1<=nt2<=...` and the old times is a subset of the new ones.

I did this the following way, but it is far too slow:

```
PadDataList[l_, grid_] :=
  Module[
   {lind = 1, len = Length@l},
   MapIndexed[(
      If[# > l[[lind, 1]] && lind < len, lind++];
      {#, l[[lind, 2]]}
      ) &,
    grid
    ]];
data = Sort[RandomReal[1, {50000, 2}], First@#1 < First@#2 &];
newgrid = Union@Join[data[[All, 1]], RandomReal[1, {50000}]];
AbsoluteTiming[PadDataList[data, newgrid];]
(* 0.4 seconds *)
```

Is there a cleverer and more efficient way to do this?

I am using this together with another function that takes multiple lists like above and creates a new list with elements `f[nti,x(i),y(i),...]`

<sub>Excuse the abuse of (i) syntax</sub>

Comment: I haven't looked at your example that carefully, but are you trying to do zero-order interpolation? If that's the case, you might take a look at `Interpolation`. It has an option called `InterpolationOrder` which you could set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether your implementation is consistent with your explanation. You wrote:

> where x(i) is equal to the xi of whichever data point is **preceding** nti

I interpret this in the following way: when we have this simple example

```
data = {{1, x1}, {2, x2}, {4, x3}};
newgrid = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

then `nti=3` clearly should get the value `x2` because this point is the *preceding* one when we insert the new time point. Your function gives

```
{{1, x1}, {2, x2}, {3, x3}, {4, x3}}
```

which I think is not what you meant, but maybe this is only a detail. Nevertheless, my implementation will return `x2` in this place.

Regarding your question whether there is a *cleverer and more efficient way* to do this I have to admit that my implementation beats your function only by about .02 seconds, but I wanted to use *highlevel* code only this time. Therefore, you better look at this as an alternate approach:

```
PadDataList[data_, grid_] := With[
  {rules = Dispatch[Rule[#1, {##}] & @@@ data]},
  FoldList[If[NumericQ[#2], {#2, Last[#1]}, #2] &, First[data], Rest[grid] /. rules]
]
```

This function works as follows: It first creates a fast set of rules from your data so that I have a list `{t1->{t1,x1}, t2->{t2,x2}, ...}`. When I apply this rule to your new grid, I get a mixed list. Times that were available are replaced to their complete `{tn,xn}` pair, while new times stay untouched.

Now I go through this list with `FoldList` and if I meet a time only (`NumericQ`), I use this time value combined with the `x` of the last pair. You may now ask how I not this last value: This is the good thing with `Fold`, because the last result is always given as first argument and we can just use it.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the bug about preceeding. I've underestimated `Dispatch` I expected rule based approach to be slower.